# Tkinter - how to use polish font inside entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Basically my tkitner app uses entry widgets. I am from Poland and i want my app to use polsih language, but when i type in entry letters that only occur in my language like: ą, ś, ć, ź, ż, ł, ę, in return i get: ¹, œ, æ, Ÿ, ¿, ³, ê.

How to fix this problem? I have already tried changing font to another.

Entries in my app look similar to this one:

```
entry = tk.Entry(window, font='Courier', 17)
entry.pack()
```

Git Hub of my app is here:
https://github.com/SzyMoe/Lucky-Dots

Comment: `in return i get: ¹, œ, æ, Ÿ, ¿, ³, ê.`.Do you mean that when you use `entry.get()`. It will show this?

Comment: Yest but from what i saw the problem is only on my computer... so i guess i will just leave this.